# Reference request for TQFT, functoriality

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, cobordism, topological-quantum-field-theory

I am reading Turaev's blue book Quantum Invariants of Knots and 3-manifolds.

It is difficult for me to understand the proof of Theorem 1.9 in chapter 4, which says;

The function $(M, \partial_{-}M, \partial_{+}M) \mapsto \tau(M): T(\partial_{-}M) \to T(\partial_{+}M)$ extends the modular functor $T$ to a non-degenerate topological quantum field theory.

The proof of the functoriality is unclear for me. I tried to look at Turaev's papers but its harder to understand. Also I don't understand the proof of computation of annomalies (Theorem 4.3 on chapter 4). The method of the proof seems to extend the method of the proof of functoriality to 4-manifolds.

Could you suggest me a textbook or paper etc that explain these theorems or similar material?

Or could you show me more detailed proof of functoriality (and the computation of anomalies) here?

Answer (score 2):

Turaev himself has reviewed this construction of a 3-dimensional TQFT in the article [Quantum 3-Manifold Invariants](http://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/TQFT/BT2.pdf) (2006). As "further reading" he suggests the 2001 lecture notes by Bakalov and Kirillov, which are published by the AMS but can be freely downloaded in a non-final form from [here.](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~kirillov/tensor/tensor.html) Chapters 4 and 5 address the Turaev-Reshetikhin construction. A quick look suggests that these lecture notes are quite gentle on the reader, and may be along the lines of what you are looking for.

> These lectures are devoted to the discussion of the relation between
>   tensor categories, modular functor, and 3D topological quantum field
>   theory. They were written as a textbook; all the results there are
>   known. Our only contribution is putting it all together, filling the
>   gaps, and simplifying some arguments.

Comment: Concerning the "non final form": it's only if you care about the last chapter that it's worth looking at the actual book. The rest of the book is pretty much identical to the online document.

Comment: As I asked in the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109774/a-proof-of-the-gluing-axiom-of-a-tqft, the proof of functoriality in Bakalov-Kirillov is not clear for me.